# Is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ a zero-content set?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

**A half-open rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$** is of the form P=$(a_1,b_1] \times \cdots (a_n,b_n]$.

The **volume of a half-open rectangle** is Vol(P)=$(b_{1}-a_{1}) \cdots (b_{n}-a_{n})$.

A set S in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to **a zero-content set** if for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a finite number of half-open rectangles $P_1,\ldots,P_k$(for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$) such that $$P_1 \cup \cdots \cup P_k \supseteq S \quad \text{and}\quad \sum_{i=1}^{k} Vol(P_i) < \varepsilon$$

Question: **Is the set $S=\{\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid ||\vec{x}||=1 \}$ a zero-content set in $\mathbb{R}^n$?**

My solution: intuitively, if we are considering $\mathbb{R}^2$,then S is a unit circle, obviously we can find some squares to cover the circle and make the total area as small as we want. but how can we prove it in $\mathbb{R}^n$? If we use the inequality $|x_i| \leq ||\vec{x}||$ ( for $1 \leq i \leq n$), we can set $P=[-1,1] \times \cdots \times [-1,1]$ then clearly $P \supseteq S$. Now we simply make $P'=(-1-\delta,1] \times \cdots \times (-1-\delta,1]$ (for some $\delta >0$) so that we have $P' \supseteq P \supseteq S$. And we partition $P'$ into k half-open rectangles such that $P_1 \cup \cdots \cup P_k=P'$.But how do we choose this $\delta$ so that $\sum_{i=1}^{k} Vol(P_i) < \varepsilon$? Does such $\delta$ really exist?

Comment: The sum of the volumes of the $P_i$s, if they are a partition of $P'$, id going to be at least $1$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: But the n-sphere can be embedded in $\mathbb R^{n+1} $ or higher , so isn't its n-th dimensional measure 0?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the $n$-sphere is embedded in $\mathbb R^{n+1} $ (Since it cannot be embedded in $\mathbb R^n$) , then its n-th dimensional measure is zero. A compact set of measure zero haszero content. I am saying yes, using total boundedness and  the general relationship : Compact equals Complete + Totally Bounded. Totally Bounded means we can cover the space ( the n-sphere here ) by finitely-many sets of any fixed size.